# How to pluck a camel case column

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to pluck a column from a table. The command seems to be failing because my column name is in camel case (`practiceType`). Here are my error, model and schema:

```
> Task.pluck 'practiceType'
   (0.5ms)  SELECT practiceType FROM "tasks"
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "practicetype" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT practiceType FROM "tasks"
               ^
: SELECT practiceType FROM "tasks"
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "practicetype" does not exist
```

**task.rb**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :practiceType
[...]
```

**schema.db**

```
  create_table "tasks", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "practiceType"
  [...]
```

The right solution is probably to convert the column name into snake case, but I prefer to avoid that for fear of breaking my app. Is there a quick and dirty solution that will get my query to run?

Comment: You might be able to use alias, i.e., `alias "practiceType", "practicetype"` (or reversed, not sure), I read that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822257/ruby-on-rails-is-it-possible-to-use-camel-cased-database-field-and-table-names

Comment: [This post](http://lexsheehan.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-reference-camelcase-column-names.html) suggests double-quoting the column name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's weird.

Try this. Seems to work fine.

```
Task.pluck('"practiceType"')
```

Comment: The first method works: `>> Task.pluck '"practiceType"'
(0.5ms)  SELECT "practiceType" FROM "tasks"`